# column of python dataframe(imported from csv file) is conflicting with python keyword, how to overcome this situtation

Tags: python, machine-learning

Hello Machine learning and Python experts,

I am trying to plot a bar graph for one of the column of a dataframe but i am getting an error as follows,

```
x_all.class.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the error is because of the column name "class" which is same as python keyword.i was told to not change the name of column "class".
How to plot graph without changing column name ?

Complete code is given below,

```
import numpy as np       
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   `enter code here`
train = pd.read_csv("network_train.csv")    
test = pd.read_csv("network_test.csv")    
x_all=pd.concat((train,test),axis=0)
x_all.class.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Screenshot of the column "class" is given [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzDqO.png)

Comment: Please can you post your code?

Comment: I agree with Adi219, the error seems not to be in the posted line. Please post more context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
getattr(x_all,'class').value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

If it doesn't work, You need to rename column name in CSV file:

```
with open("network_train.csv") as infile, open('new_network_train.csv','w') as outfile: 
for line in infile: 
    outfile.write(line.replace('class','class1'))

with open("network_test.csv") as infile, open('new_network_test.csv','w') as outfile: 
for line in infile: 
    outfile.write(line.replace('class','class1'))
```

And use new files.

Comment: getattr(x_all,'class').value_counts().plot(kind='bar') ---------- this worked. thanks much Fatahzade